# Nginx How to do 301 redirect from old domain to new domain except few URL

Tags: 301-redirect, nginx

I am using nginx and trying to redirect all users from old domain to new domains.,

using this configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return       301 https://new-example.com$request_uri;
}
```

But while doing this, i want to access directory which is on old domain,

e.g. 
i want to access `example.com/datafiles/`

but while using above code every request gets 301 redirected to new domain and url becomes

```
new-example.com/datafiles/
```

i dont want urls containing `example.com/datafiles/` to gets redirected to new domain.

How can i achieve something like this ?

so far i have tried this.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    #set location for sitemaps directory
    location /datafiles/ {
        root   /usr/local/nginx/html/example.com/html;
    }

    return       301 https://new-example.com$request_uri;
   }
```

but still requests to

```
example.com/datafiles/
```

gets redirected to

```
new-example.com/datafiles/
```

what am i missing here ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857334/nginx-redirect-everything-from-http-to-https-except-one-url-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    #set location for sitemaps directory
    location ~ ^/datafiles/ {
        root   /usr/local/nginx/html/example.com/html;
    }
    location / {
    return       301 https://new-example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.